Quick way to solve the system $C^2 - D^2 = 12$, $C - D = 2$
Forgive my stupidity, I have been out of school for twenty years and I forgot the names. My daughter has this question on her homework:

$$\begin{align}C^2 - D^2 &= 12 \\
C\phantom{^2} - D\phantom{^2} &= \phantom{1}2 \end{align}$$
What is the value of $C$ ?
What is the value of $D$ ?

From basic observation, I got $C = 4$ and $D = 2$, but how do I teach my daughter to solve it without trying random numbers? What is the formula and what is this called?

Hint:  Expand $(C-D)^2$.  That gives you a value for $2CD$.  Use that to get a value for $(C+D)^2$, finish from there.

@lulu, thanks for those steps, but I am too old to remember what the finishing steps are.

As an alternative, use the fact that $C=D+2$ to eliminate $C$ from the top equation.  Now you can just solve for $D$.  This method is easier.

Please change the tag from elementary-number-theory to algebra. This ensures the quality of this site and helps categorize posts correctly.

@Amogh changed per your suggestion.

2 ways to solve, 1 way includes noticing a difference of the squares as many have pointed out and then expanding that. 2nd way is involving a simple algebraic manipulation and binomial expansion. I'd say the 2nd way is easier if you haven't done this in a while since it can be challenging to notice the difference of the squares.

For what it's worth, the basic observation that you made is great. I would encourage your daughter to spend at least a little time with such exercises looking for basic observations before moving to something more methodical. In this case, you know one number is 2 larger than the other. What if solutions are integers? It's then quick to just test a few small integers along with the number that is 2 larger.

Not sure about the hint to expand $(C-D)^2$. That does not quickly give $2CD$ because the sign on $D^2$ different from the other equation.

Use the fact that $C^2-D^2=(C-D)(C+D)$ , where the Multiplication is the well known factorization.
We then get :
$(C-D)(C+D)=12 \tag{0}$
$(C-D)=2 \tag{1}$
Divide these to get :
$C+D=6 \tag{2}$
Use (1) with (2) to get , via Addition  :
$2C=8 \tag{3}$
Use (1) with (2) to get , via Subtraction  :
$2D=4 \tag{4}$
Hence the Solution is $(C,D)=(4,2)$
ADDENDUM :
The letters are generally known as variables or unknowns or unknown variables.
It is not called Equation (Singular) when there are 2 or more Equations.
What you have is called System of Equations (Plural) or Simultaneous Equations (Plural) because you have 2 Equations here.
In the most general terms , there is no "formula" like the Quadratic Equation Case.
Maybe , there are "methods" , like Substitution , Elimination , Matrix , Etc , though listing that [ with sufficient elaboration ] will only confuse , while taking us too far from the Query here.

Use the identity $a^2-b^2 \equiv (a+b)(a-b)$ to simplify the first equation to $(C+D)(C-D)=12$
We know $(C-D) = 2$, so $(C+D)(2) = 12$, which gives us $(C+D)=6$
Now we know the sum of $C$ and $D$, as well as the difference of $C$ and $D$
$$C+D=6$$
$$C-D=2$$
Adding the two equations, we get
$$2C+D-D=6+2$$
$$2C+0=8$$
$$2C=8$$
This means $C=4$, which we can substitute into any of the above equations, say, $C-D=2$, to get
$$4-D=2$$
Giving us $D=2$

Using the identity
$(C+D)(C-D) = C^2 - D^2$
you have that your system is equivalent to
$(C+D)(C-D) = 12 $
$C-D = 2$
Hence, substituting the second equation into the first one and dividing by 2, it yields:
$C+D = 6 $
$C-D = 2$
From here you sum both equations and obtain
$2C = 8$
concluding that $C = 4$. Now, using any of the above equations you substitute the value of $C$ and you obtain $D = 2$.

We have that $C^2-D^2=12$ and $C-D=2$.
This yields $(C-D)(C+D)=2 \cdot (C+D)=12$.
We know now that $C+D=6$
This gives $2C=8 \iff C=4$ and therefore $D=2$.

From $C-D=2$ we can multiply by both $C$ and $D$ to get
$$C^2-CD=2C$$
$$CD-D^2=2D$$
Add these to get $C^2-D^2=2C+2D$, so $2C+2D=12$ and then $C+D=6$.
Then $C=4,D=2$.
